# Uploading dragged images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I was making a uploading system in php, Before you can choose an image. Now you can either choose an image or just drag the image on the uploading system. The problem that I'm having, If I choose and image and then upload it, It works fine and the name of the images are shown before uploading but when I drag an image the names are shown but I can't seem to upload it. Is there anyway to fix this problem I'm having, I have no idea how to fix it.

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
        <div class="add-form">
            <h1 class="text-center"><font face="fantasy" size = "10"><center>Please Insert new image</center></font></h1>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormID" onsubmit="uploadFiles(event)">
                <label for = "name" id = "LabelName"><font face = fantasy size = "5">
                <img src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1233/1233986.png" width = "50">
                 <br>
                 UserName</font></label>
                <input class = "UsernameUpload" id = "name" type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control">

                <label for = "image" id = "fileLabel"
                ondragover = "overrideDefault(event);fileHover();"
                ondragenter = "overrideDefault(event);fileHover();"
                ondragleave = "overrideDefault(event);fileHoverEnd();"
                ondrop = "overrideDefault(event);fileHoverEnd();addFiles(event);">



                <font face = "fantasy" size = "5">
                <img src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1180/premium/1180674.png" width = "50">
                 <br>

                 <span id = "fileLabelText">Select image to upload Or Drag N Drop</font></span>
                 <br>
                 </label>

                <input multiple onchange = "addFiles(event)" id = "image" type="file"  onchange ="unlock()" name="profile" class="form-control2" accept="*/image">
                <button class = "uploadButton" type="submit" value = "submit" name="btn-add" onClick = "return validate()" action = "index.php"><font face = "calibri" size = "4">upload</font></button>
                <div id = "error"><font face = "fantasy">Please fill up the username and select and image</font></div>


            </form>
        </div>
        <hr style="border-bottom: 5px blue solid;">
    </div>
```

Css code:

```
<style type = "text/css">

body{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#FormID {
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#FormID #fileLabel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#FormID #image {
  display: none;
}

#FormID #fileLabel:after,
#FormID #fileLabel:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: -2;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

#FormID #fileLabel:before {
  z-index: -1;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 5%,
    black 5%,
    black 10%
  );
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#FormID.fileHover #fileLabel:before {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

#FormID .uploadButton {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: limeGreen;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#FormID.fileHover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px limeGreen;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>

function validate()
{

    var username = document.getElementById("name");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");


    if(username.value.trim()=="") {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        username.style.border = "solid 3px red";
        myDiv.innerHTML = '<font face = "fantasy" size="4" color = "red">username not entered</font>';
        return false;
    }
    else if (username.value.length<8){
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        username.style.border = "solid 3px red";
        myDiv.innerHTML = '<font face = "fantasy" size="4" color = "red">username need to be atleast 8 characters long</font>';
        return false;
    }
    else if (img.value.trim()=="") {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        img.style.border = "solid 3px red";
        myDiv.innerHTML = '<font face = "fantasy" size="4" color = "red">Please Select an image</font>';
        return false;
    }


}
var FormID = document.getElementById("FormID");
var fileLabelText = document.getElementById("fileLabelText");
var uploadStatus = document.getElementById("uploadStatus");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var droppedFiles;

function overrideDefault(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function fileHover() {
  FormID.classList.add("fileHover");
}

function fileHoverEnd() {
  FormID.classList.remove("fileHover");
}

function addFiles(event) {
  droppedFiles = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
  showFiles(droppedFiles);
}

function showFiles(files) {
  if (files.length > 1) {
    fileLabelText.innerText = files.length + " files selected";
  } else {
    fileLabelText.innerText = files[0].name;
  }
}

</script>
```

EDIT: This is PHP code also:

```
<?php 
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
    {
        $stmt_select=$db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id=:uid');
        $stmt_select->execute(array(':uid'=>$_GET['delete_id']));
        $imgRow=$stmt_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        unlink("uploads/".$imgRow['picprofile']);
        $stmt_delete=$db_conn->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl_user WHERE id =:uid');
        $stmt_delete->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['delete_id']);
        if($stmt_delete->execute())
        {
            ?>
            <script>

            window.location.href=('index.php');
            </script>
            <?php 
        }else

        ?>
            <script>

            window.location.href=('index.php');
            </script>
            <?php 

    }

    ?>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['btn-add']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $images=$_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $path = "uploads/";
        $rand=rand(1000, 1000000);
        $filename = "$rand.jpg";
        $filepath = "$path$filename";

                function correctImageOrientation($filename) {
  if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
      $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
      if($orientation != 1){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        $deg = 0;
        switch ($orientation) {
          case 3:
            $deg = 180;
            break;
          case 6:
            $deg = 270;
            break;
          case 8:
            $deg = 90;
            break;
        }
        if ($deg) {
          $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);        
        }
        // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename 
        imagejpeg($img, $filename, 95);
      } // if there is some rotation necessary
    } // if have the exif orientation info
  } // if function exists      
}

        $imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)){ 
            $images = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);       
        }

         correctImageOrientation($filepath);


        if ($imgExt == "jpeg" || $imgExt == "jpg") {
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
        }else if($imgExt == "png"){
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
        }else if($imgExt == "gif"){
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);
        }
        $size = getimagesize($filepath);

             $width = imagesx($im);
             $height = imagesy($im);
             $newwidth= 800;
             $newheight= 800;



                if(($width/$newwidth) < ($height/$newheight)){
                    $y = 0;
                    $x = $width - (($height * $newwidth) / $newheight);
                }else{
                    $x = 0;
                    $y = $height - (($width * $newheight) / $newwidth);
                }


             $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor(850, 850);    
             imagealphablending($virtual_image, true);
             imagesavealpha($virtual_image, true);

             imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$im,0,0, $x/2, $y/2, $newwidth, $newheight, $width-$x, $height-$y); 
             $bgcolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($virtual_image,255,255,255,127);


             imagefill($virtual_image,0,0,$bgcolor);

             imagecolortransparent($virtual_image, $bgcolor);


             imagejpeg($virtual_image,$filepath,100);



            $stmt=$db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_user(username, picprofile) VALUES (:uname, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic', $filename);
            if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Uploaded";
            header("Location:index.php");

        }else

        {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("Error");
                window.location.href=('index.php');
            </script>
        <?php
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: What browsers are you supporting? For recent ones it's as easy as `function showFiles(files) { img.files = files; //... what you already have` for older browsers, you'd need to use AJAX to send your files, and there are many examples already out there.